# MITM with winpcap and/or sockets? - C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, winpcap

i am developing an MITM for windows. I am using winpcap. I did correctly the arp spoofing and the ip fordwarding to the victims of my network. The problem of winpcap is that you cant control the packets, you need sockets to do this.

With winpcap you read incoming packets, you filter them, change them and send to  router ok, easy. The problem comes when you need to act as a server. For example, if we want to supplant an executable we need to serve our own exe. And we cant use sockets to serve our file to the victims because we are using winpcap, we must create all the packet and send it with pcap_sendpacket(), we must hear the victim responses, how?, the only way is waiting all incoming packets from all victims and from different protocols and to filter all searching our ACK, for all packets tcp in the download.

Is this way viable? Or shall i create a server in each sniffer port and to do this with sockets?. Mmmm ideas pls. What is better, and what would you do?

Thanks and sorry for my English :)

Regards!.

Comment: You need to look into Scapy.  Beyond that, I think your question is too broad for this SO.

Comment: So i should use winpcap? You talk about Scapy, but with scapy is used to build packets no?, i dont need that, i can create the packets byte to byte, and send to the network with pcap_sendpacket(), the problem is that i must control the responses, checksums, sequence numbers..., and i must hear the ACKS and to act in response. I need ideas, solutions. Scapy is to create packets, thats not the problem.

Comment: Scapy is used to both sniff and to build packets.  You can absolutely implement what you are describing with Scapy.

Comment: If i can do it with Scapy i also can do it with winpcap, with winpcap you can do bot sniff and to build packets. But that dosent answer my question. Furthermore Scapy is written in python, and i am working with C++. I only asked what is better to do the sniffer winpcap, sockets, or winpcap and sockets (open servers). With winpcap i cant control the responses, the only way to do that is reading all incoming packets and to search the response (ACK), i only want to know if that is viable. Thank you.

Comment: Anything is possible if you're willing to put in the effort.  Scapy will make your life far easier since all of the mechanics of manipulating packets and streams are fully developed.  I'll post an answer with the technical requirements regardless since this hasn't been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  Here are the steps that you need to take to do this successfully.

1. Identify an unused IP address on the subnet.  If you try to use the address that is already bound you will be racing against and fighting the IP stack in the host OS.  Since it knows nothing of the connections that you're managing/spoofing, it will send `RST` packets in reaction to almost every response packet that you receive (Note, I'm assuming that you're using TCP)
2. Select a MAC that you will use.  You actually *can* use the same MAC as the host OS network stack, which will allow you to operate without actually putting the interface into promiscuous mode.  The host OS will *not* interfere since the Layer 2 addresses will not match the host OS's knowledge of the Layer 2 address, but you will still have to supply ARP replies for your Layer 2 address when other host look for you.
3. Effectively, write your own IP stack.  Yes, you will be responsible for calculating checksums, tracking session state and everything else.

A far easier approach that you seem to be resistant to is to use Scapy.  Scapy abstracts much of this for you, allowing you to focus on the logic of what it is you're actually trying to do.  For example, [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) will take care of the checksums for you if you'd like it to.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It was that i thougth i have to create all network layers to form my packet (Ehternet, IP, TCP..). About the step one i think it dosent necessary, because victims of the network dosent use my IP to communicate with me (OS IP), because they think i am the router. I spoof the router IP with my mac, if i do that i shouldnt generate conflicts between OS and the sniffer, because OS uses his own IP and sniffer uses router IP. About IP stack, it wont be easy, but i just implemented the checksums satisfactorily, i think that the worst will come with sequence numbers etc Regards!

Comment: However, on the ethernet layer there are conlficts between OS and sniffer, cause of the arp spoofing. But them must be ignored, because is the only way to spoof on the ethernet layer, and its the most simple than other protocols to spoof.

Comment: There will be no conflicts.  The TCP/IP stack will drop any packets that are passed to it that do not have what the OS believes is the assigned IP address or a broadcast address (or a network address, if you were in UNIX, but you're not.)